# Apps Script, SQL DB, and VPN

Tags: sql, database, google-apps-script, vpn

How can I access a SQL Database using Apps Script when the database is behind a firewall and can only be accessed through a VPN.

I've tried running an Apps Script program while my computer is logged into the VPN, however, every attempt fails.  At the same time I can access the database through software i.e. SQLyog without any issue.

Thoughts anyone?

Link to accessing SQL through Apps Script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc

Comment: is this still a case?

Comment: It's been a while since I've faced this issue.   I don't remember exactly what I did, however, I do remember vpn/firewall white listing apps script's IP address: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt (listed here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#using_jdbcgetconnectionurl > 1 > data source)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant. Scripts run on google servers Not your browser/pc.
You would need sdc but its deprecated.