# Google App Script throw BAD request , Postman and Curl OK, even browser callback

Tags: google-apps-script, gitlab

I am trying to run the below code over the Google App Script for Gitlab which is in VPN.

The VPN is connected and I can get responses on Curl Command, Browser, and Postman but the Google App script is giving an error.

```
this._url = "https://<url access on vpn and vpn is on>/api/v4/projects/1048/repository/compare?to=release%2F1.209.0&from=release%2F1.208.0"; this.payloadData = null;

this.fetchArgs = {   contentType: "application/json",   headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer <mytoken-accesible on Postmand and Curl>" },  muteHttpExceptions: true,   method: methodType, }

try {   this.responseData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(this._url, this.fetchArgs);   this.responseCode = this.responseData.getResponseCode(); } catch (e) {   console.log(e); }
```

Response is always as below

```
{ [Exception: Bad request: https://<baseURL>/api/v4/projects/1048/repository/compare?to=release%2F1.209.0&from=release%2F1.208.0] name: 'Exception' }
```

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the API you want to use? For example, from `I can get responses on Curl Command`, can you provide your curl command?

Comment: The issue was resolved hence I put my answer to the question asked as the answer is for JIRA, not Gitlab hence not accepted that but pasted below for Gitlab to have the same rule. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html command as asked is put for reference which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need VPN to access the link, and you were able to access it using Postman, curl and browser but apps script doesn't, that is because all those 3 accesses the URL locally thus they can access it with VPN.

In the other hand, Apps Script does that remotely (they run on google servers), therefore, you are accessing the URL without any VPN, causing the bad request issue.

It is said that you could use [SDC](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/) for these issues but it is already deprecated.

#### Reference:

- [Apps Script, SQL DB, and VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618946/17842569)
- [Does code on a Google sheet runs locally or on a Google server? - UrlFetchApp returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461797/does-code-on-a-google-sheet-runs-locally-or-on-a-google-server-urlfetchapp-re)